# No route found for "GET /login/" symfony3

Tags: symfony, authentication, routes, fosuserbundle

i'm working with FOSUserBundle in Symfony 3.3 
the login worked before but now it's not working saying No route found for "GET /login/" 
i type "/login" but it redirect me to "/login/" , i don't know whats happening 
i tried to fix it, but i failed :(
this is my security.yml :

```
security:
        encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

        providers:
            fos_userbundle:
                id: fos_user.user_provider.username

        firewalls:
            main:
                pattern: ^/
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    login_path: /login
                    check_path: /login_check
                    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                logout:
                        path:   /logout
                        target: /login
                anonymous:   true

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and this is  app/routing.yml

```
stage_admin:
    resource: "@StageAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

stage_controller:
    resource: "@StageAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

this is all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
        prefix="/profile" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
        prefix="/register" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
        prefix="/resetting" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
        prefix="/profile" />
</routes>
```

when i type : php bin/console debug:router , i found that the rout /login exist ..

```
_wdt                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar                ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_info                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
  _profiler_phpinfo                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results            ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css             ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _twig_error_test                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  stage_admin_homepage                ANY        ANY      ANY    /
  stage_admin_federation              ANY        ANY      ANY    /federation
  stage_admin_joueur                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /joueur
  fos_user_security_login             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /login
  fos_user_security_check             POST       ANY      ANY    /login_check
  fos_user_security_logout            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /logout
  fos_user_profile_show               GET        ANY      ANY    /profile/
  fos_user_profile_edit               GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /profile/edit
  fos_user_registration_register      GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /register/
  fos_user_registration_check_email   GET        ANY      ANY    /register/check-email
  fos_user_registration_confirm       GET        ANY      ANY    /register/confirm/{token}
  fos_user_registration_confirmed     GET        ANY      ANY    /register/confirmed
  fos_user_resetting_request          GET        ANY      ANY    /resetting/request
  fos_user_resetting_send_email       POST       ANY      ANY    /resetting/send-email
  fos_user_resetting_check_email      GET        ANY      ANY    /resetting/check-email
  fos_user_resetting_reset            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /resetting/reset/{token}
  fos_user_change_password            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /profile/change-password
  federation_index                    GET        ANY      ANY    /federation/
  federation_new                      GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /federation/new
  federation_show                     GET        ANY      ANY    /federation/{id}
  federation_edit                     GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /federation/{id}/edit
  federation_delete                   DELETE     ANY      ANY    /federation/{id}
  joueur_index                        GET        ANY      ANY    /joueur/
  joueur_new                          GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /joueur/new
  joueur_show                         GET        ANY      ANY    /joueur/{id}
  joueur_edit                         GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /joueur/{id}/edit
  joueur_delete                       DELETE     ANY      ANY    /joueur/{id}
  homepage                            ANY        ANY      ANY    /
```

please help me :) thanks

EDIT : the solution is : i added a new SecurityContoller in my own bundle , by copying the content of SecurityContoller of FOSUserBundle and i added the route "login" in it

```
<?php

namespace Stage\AdminBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

/**
 * Federation controller.
 *
 * @Route("login")
 */

class SecurityContoller extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;

        // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }

        if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
        }

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);

        $csrfToken = $this->has('security.csrf.token_manager')
            ? $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue()
            : null;

        return $this->renderLogin(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Renders the login template with the given parameters. Overwrite this function in
     * an extended controller to provide additional data for the login template.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    protected function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig', $data);
    }

    public function checkAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue time ago, try adding a 'default' entry to your firewalls

```
firewalls:
    default:
        pattern: ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
```

Comment: @MaryemSamet Do you have a defined route in a controller with the name "/login"?

Comment: @MaryemSamet you should at least define a route in some controller with the route "/login", it should be empty but at least declared

Comment: thank u  , it works now , i just added a new  SecurityController in my own bundle  by copying the content of SecurityController of FOSUserBunlde   ,and i added the route like u said . 
its solved now , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
security:
        encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

        providers:
            fos_userbundle:
                id: fos_user.user_provider.username

        firewalls:
            main:
                pattern: .*
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    login_path: /login
                    check_path: /login_check
                    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                logout:
                        path:   /logout
                        target: /login
                anonymous:   true

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And change to Sha512:

```
security:
        encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

Comment: i tried that but still saying No route found for "GET /login/"

Comment: i solved it by adding a new SecurityController in my Bundle , and i added the root "/root" in it .. 
thank u for helping me